# Java post request with nested objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have an object `Order` which contains another object `Person` among other properties.

I'm wondering what is the best solution to create an order through a post request.

---

The first approach in my mind is something like this:

```
@PostMapping("orders/create")
public void createOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

but what I don't like about this solution is that the client has to send a json string with all the information about the order and the person at the same time, like this:

```
{
    "date": 2023-01-01,
    "price": 10,
    "person": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I also make sure that the person passed in the request is actually a person that exists in my database?

---

The second approach that I can think of is like this:

```
@PostMapping("orders/create/{personId}")
public void createOrder(@PathVariable Long personId, @RequestBody Order order) {
    Person person = personRepository.findById(personId).orElseThrow();
    order.setPerson(person);
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

but this solution would require a post request like `localhost:8080/orders/1` where 1 is the id of the person, which is horrible because it's too confusing.

I can't get my head around this, any insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are users of this endpoint authenticated, and that mapped to your Person entities?

Comment: Aside: it's not the best idea to include verbs in your endpoint paths (ie, "create"). Think of REST URLs as _resources_, with the HTTP verbs representing _actions_. So `POST` is inherently (by convention) a "create" action, and a `POST` to the resource named "orders" represents a request to create a new resource under that one.

Comment: Ideally, you get the `Person` object that represents the user that is currently logged in. At least I assume that the logged in user is the one placing the order.

Comment: There's no authentication involved here, it's a simple project and I didn't implement it yet.

@E-Riz oh ok thank you, so it makes more sense to write @PostMapping("orders")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't make sense to send the personId to the order API.  Since you're passing the personId in the RequestBody, just drop the PathVariable and use what's in the order.

```
@PostMapping("orders/create")
public void createOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
   Person person = personRepository.findById(order.getPerson().getId()).orElseThrow();
   order.setPerson(person);
   orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

Or, as the comment by E-Riz is eluding to, if the Person is the authenticated user, get them out of the SecurityContext and look them up by their username.  Then there would be no need to send the Person in the Order.

Comment: I recommend putting this "assembly" logic in a service layer. It's usually best to keep the API layer as thin as possible; in particular, not referencing data-access layer  (repositories) directly.

Comment: Please see the comment by @E-Riz; this is an important point.  All three lines in this method should be pushed down into a service that takes the Order and returns the persisted order.  To take this one step further, you should probably receive a DTO instead of the Entity.